# Modular Congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to somehow use mod 2 and Modular congruence to prove whether or not the following number is even or odd:
$722^{77}$-$333^{99}$($55^{100}$)
What I was thinking about doing was evaluating as two different mod 2's and subtracting them so I get 0-1 which gives me -1. So that would mean it's odd right? I really don't know what to do with this. Help appreciated.

Comment: You can do this even without knowing any fancy congruence stuff. First number is even second number is odd. An even minus an odd number is?(?) But yes you're reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would do as follows, assuming that $-333^{99}(55^{100})$ means $-((333^{99})*(55^{100}))$ :

$(722^{77}-333^{99}(55^{100}))\quad mod \quad 2 = $

$((722^{77}) \quad mod \quad 2) - ((333^{99}(55^{100})) \quad mod \quad 2) = $

$(722 \quad mod \quad 2)^{77} - ((333 \quad mod \quad 2)^{99}(55 \quad mod \quad 2)^{100})) = $

$(0)^{77} - ((1)^{99}(1)^{100}) = 0 - 1 = -1$